# How do I remove all of the data on a harddrive partition without removing/altering the filesystem?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, format

I have a drive that has corrupted data on it.  I need to wipe all of the data on that hard drive partition without altering the filesystem because I cannot rebuild the filesystem (It'd a very old version of XFS and cannot be upgraded, it is in an arcade machine).

Comment: You dont upgrade filesystems. Use gparted to format it or 'rm' to remove contents.

Comment: I will try gparted, I am not sure if I have attempted to remove the data that way.  RM doesn't work because of the corruption sadly.

Comment: If you want to clean it up what's the purpose of keeping the partition as is, why don't you just reformat? Does the arcade machine support that specific version of XFS only?

Comment: Case: you should format it then , gparted will tell you what format it can to.

Comment: Yes, rm -rf results in directory not empty.   Corrupted data, not the drive I checked that as well.